# React useState array update

Tags: reactjs, setstate, react-functional-component

I have tried a few things but I cannot get the state of this array to update at all. I am sure I am close but can someone please take a look and tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks

```
const [totals, setTotals] = useState({
    1: 0,
    2: 0,
    3: 0,
    4: 0,
    5: 0,
    6: 0,
    7: 0,
    8: 0,
    9: 0,
    10: 0,
    11: 0,
    12: 0
});

const handleCalculations = (key, value) => {
    setTotals({
        ...totals,
        [key]:  totals[key] + value
    });
}
```

Comment: Looks OK to me at first glance. Can you show how you wire up `handleCalculations`? Maybe `value` is a string so you are mixing up addition with concatenation?

Comment: @kevin3954 you describe it as an array, but the code shows a non-array object. Both are possible, but could you clarify which one you want?

Comment: What exactly goes wrong? Does the state get updated at all? Can you confirm it hits your `handleCalculations` function with the expected inputs? (e.g. add a `console.log`)

Comment: Yes it hits the function. Console log shows the key and value as both integer. Nothing gets updated at all though

Comment: How did you confirm that "nothing gets updated"? By examining the UI? I would `console.log(totals)` right before your `return` function so you can examine the raw state on each re-render. Also, your original object is `1-12` but you are rendering `0-11`, so that could be problematic.

Answer (score 2):

I have a suspicion that you are calling `handleCalculations` incorrectly.
You most likely use it like this

```
<button onClick={handleCalculations}>click me</button>
```

As a result, event, which is an object, comes to the `handleCalculations`.

As a result, your state becomes like this:

```js
{
    1: 0,
    2: 0,
    3: 0,
    4: 0,
    5: 0,
    6: 0,
    7: 0,
    8: 0,
    9: 0,
    10: 0,
    11: 0,
    12: 0,
    12: 0,
    "[object Object]": null,
}
```

Try passing correct parameters to the handler, like this

```
<button onClick={()=>handleCalculations(12,1)}>click me</button>
```

This should fix the problem.

Substitute the parameters into the function in accordance with your logic.

Comment: This answer is correct in a way. But regarding the current code provided by @kevin3954 he passes `handeCalculations` to `Row` component. So in that component, he could say:

```
<DateField
                    date={date}
                    bill={props.bill}
                    index={index}
                    paycheckFrequency={props.paycheckFrequency}
                    handleCalculations={() => props.handleCalculations(12, 1)}
                />
```

Comment: @kevin3954, thank you for completing your question. Can I ask you to do a minimal reproducible example example and post it on https://codesandbox.io?

Comment: I will do that. Thanks for the help. @WilfredMulenga, you are correct that does update the value. However, I need it to update with a value that will later be designated in the child element inside of useEffect. The value of 1 is just a test value to see if I can get it to update. And the key of 12 will also get passed to the child. Maybe I am looking at it the wrong way. Maybe there is a better way to do what I am trying to accomplish. I am pretty new to React. PHP is my background. I will post this example to codesandbox to see if I can make more sense. Thanks everyone

Comment: By Drew Reese
You pass handleCalculations to Row which passes it to DateField/TableCell within a loop, and TableCell invokes it upon component mounting. You've enqueued a bunch of state updates in a loop and they all update from the same current state of the render cycle they are enqueued in.

Solution
Use a functional state update to enqueue each update and have each one update from the previous computed state, not the state from the previous render cycle.

const handleCalculations = (key, value) => {
  setTotals(totals => ({
    ...totals,
    [key]: totals[key] + value
  }));
};